# return txt file from lambda function to be displayed in browser

Tags: python, url, text, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

This is what I am using in a lambda function to return the contents of a text file in a variable when a query is sent via API gateway

From Lambda

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as content_file:
        content = content_file.read()

    return content
```

but the problem is when I am opening the api gateway url and the results are returned , the variable content is stripping new lines and carriage return and all other formatting.

Is it possible to just return the file.txt and when api gateway returns the result it just opens the file content on the browser?

something like when I open the url with query

```
https://foobaar.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Beta/filename?ticket_id_api=b663fa83-874c-4a39-a1e0-741da5c6eec2
```

Comment: That’s strange, have you checked the contents before they’re returned?

Answer (score 0):

The response was being processed by the API gateway as JSON thus browser was treaing it as JSON.

- Created a "Mapping Template" in "Integration Response" with content-type set to "text/plain"
- content-type set to "text/plain" in "Response Body for 200" under "Method Execution"